# Check which image is currently shown? WPF

Tags: c#, wpf, code-behind

I got a label which triggers this function everytime I press enter

```
private void WordInput_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
        {
            WordInput.Text = String.Empty;
            Smiley.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"FailSmile2.png", UriKind.Relative));
        }
    }
```

Which changes a picture to the one above(FailSmile2.png)
But now, I want to check, if it's FailSmile2 that is being shown, then I want to change to another picture instead, with the same function. Should I use a cuople of IF to check the source? In that case, how?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Could just store it as a private field on your class:

```
private string CurrentImagePath;

private void WordInput_KeyDown(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Key == Key.Enter)
    {
        WordInput.Text = String.Empty;

        if (CurrentImagePath == null)
            CurrentImagePath = @"FailSmile2.png";
        else if (CurrentImagePath == @"FailSmile2.png")
            CurrentImagePath = @"SomeOtherImage.png";

        Smiley.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(CurrentImagePath, UriKind.Relative));
    }
}
```

Not sure about what *exactly* you want to do. If you plan on cycling through multiple images, it may be better to store those in a `List<Uri>` and cycle through them one at a time. Essentially, *somehow* you'll want to store the current state of your control (likely as a private field) and based on that make changes or possibly wire different events.

Comment: Thanks for reply! Right now, I just want a effecient way to change image when clicking. Later I will add a function with a bool to check wether something is true or not, depending on the bool 2 (or more) different image shows. Maybe I should come back later when I got all the methods done. =))